# Synonyms, Outer Joins, Single Row String Functions

Tags: mysql

How do i Return the employee id and the total number of orders that each employee processed from the orders table, sort the total from highest number to lowest.

Comment: This is a different question, I updated the query in the last question

Comment: Welcome to The Stack from a week ago. Note I will change tags here too. 4 out of 5 are not relevant. Also, people answer questions. Respond to them prior to asking a duplicate or near duplicate. The Stack doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` to count the number of orders for each employee, and `ORDER BY` to sort the results.

```
SELECT employee_id, COUNT(*) AS order_count
FROM orders
GROUP BY employee_id
ORDER BY order_count DESC
```

No need for a `JOIN` or any string functions.